# How can I replace some element and remove some element in one loop in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I wanna do some thing like this :

```
List<Integer> list = [1,2,1,3];
for (each : list) {
    if (each == 1) {
        remove (each);
    } else {
        each = 4;
    }
}
```

after the loop the list is supposed to be [4,4].

I have tried the following codes :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "1", "3"));
for (String i : list) {
    if (i.equals("1")) {
        i = "4";
    }
}
```

But it doesn't change the value, the list is [2,3].

```
List<Integer> list = [1,2,1,3];
for (int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++) {
    //do something to replace the element
}
```

This can replace the element but can not remove the element.

The only way I can come up with is to remove the elements in one loop, and replace the element in another loop, how can I do both in just one loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your following code doesn't work:

```
for (String i : list) {
    if (i.equals("1")) {
        i = "4";
    }
}
```

because you're replacing the value of String `i` instead of the selected item of list.

You need to use [set](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List#set(int,%20E)) method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    String item = list.get(i);
    if (item.equals("1")) {
        list.set(i, "4");
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE

If you want to remove and change the item in one loop, you need to use `listIterator` and change for loop with while loop:

```
ListIterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()){
   String item = iterator.next();
   
   // Change item value
   if(item.equals("1") iterator.set("4");
  
   // remove item
   if(item.equals("2") iterator.remove();
}
```

Please be noted, I haven't test the code yet.

Comment: yeah, I can replace the value throw this but I can't remove some of them without using iterator.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the updated code works. @ישו אוהב אותך

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful to avoid a ConcurrentModificationException when attempting to remove an element from a list while iterating over it. You can use this:

```
list = list.stream()
        .filter(element -> element != 1)
        .map(element -> 4)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Actually,  the result of this answer is a list of boolean, it doesn't work.

Comment: The `map` should be replaced with `map(element -> 4)`

Comment: Yeah, typo. Sorry about that.